# Retrieving buffer from Google Drive failed using google-api-nodejs v.25

Tags: node.js, google-api

I used to write a robot to retrieve Word Documents (.docx) from my Google Drive using Google Drive API v3, and all the things did run smoothly, until about 2 weeks ago, when googleapis package has been upgraded to v.25.

At first, I found that drive.files.get no longer return a stream, so using .on / .pipe methods as those documented in API Guides keeps getting failed. I tried to use callback instead as documented in Migration Guides on GitHub, I think the code below retrieve a correct response, and it seems that the document buffer is present in response.data after inspecting the response:

```
function getBuffer(auth, fileId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    drive.files.get({
      auth: auth,
      userId: 'me',
      fileId: fileId,
      alt: 'media'
    }, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        reject('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      }
      resolve(response.data);
    });
  });
}
```

However, when I try to put the buffer into mammoth, it always complain that the buffer is corrupted. I also tried to save the buffer into a .docx file and tried to open it in MS Word but with no luck. Is there anyone who figured out how to change the code to make it works with googleapis v.25 ? Thanks for reading.

Comment: At Drive API v3, ``alt=media`` is used, the data is ``response`` in your script. By this, I think that ``response.data`` shows ``undefined``.

Comment: when I try to inspect the response, response.data shows a very long string, with many unrecognized characters and "PK" at the beginning, which shows that it is a zip file (a .docx document uses zip as the wrapper). I think the problem many be about the encoding, but no luck after tried to force all the encodings which node.js supports (including null)

Comment: Finally I find the changes needed by digging into the samples from official repository. I need to add {responseType: 'stream'} in the arguments, and the method no longer throws a stream directly.
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. I couldn't notice about this from your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373224/node-js-google-drive-api-download-file-error/50381086#50381086 I'm sorry.