# Node.js Google Drive api Download file error

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const Auth = require('../authorization/auth_drive/auth');

// get data
var gotData = function downloadFiles(fileId, callback) {
    let content = fs.readFileSync('./GEARS/authorization/client_secret.json');
    Auth(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => {
        //const returnData = [];
        const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

        const fileId = '';
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream('./test_files/test.png');

        drive.files.get({fileId: fileId, alt: 'media'})
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Done');
        })
        .on('error', err => {
            console.log('Error', err);
        })
        .pipe(dest);
    });
};

module.exports = gotData;
```

Following the google documentation [LINK](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia)

All other functions I have tried, like List, Copy, Upload or Sheets Read&Write work perfectly for me, except for the Download. My application instantly crashes with the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

I have looked at Google's Sample of this very functionality, and I have not found anything that differs, so why does it work for Google Developers, while for me it doesn't?

I have not found a single person with this problem on google, so maybe, if you understand what should be done, you can see what I am doing wrong.

-- I will include [THIS LINK](https://pastebin.com/XmXrLPar), that is a Copy function I have, which works perfectly, in case it would be relevant.

*Thanks for any advice.*

Comment: I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Sry, I was just testing how the points system works on SO, didn't know you'd get notified the second I changed anything. I actually get more points by marking your answer. I did say I did it differently, so practically yours wasn't my solution but it would work as well, that's why I marked it before and I stand behind the mark, I was just curious here for a sec.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have altered Google's example. This way it works:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const Auth = require('../authorization/auth_drive/auth');

// get data
var gotData = function downloadFiles(fileId, destination, callback) {
    let content = fs.readFileSync('./GEARS/authorization/client_secret.json');
    Auth(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => {
        const returnData = [];
        const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

        const file = fs.createWriteStream(destination); // destination is path to a file

        drive.files.get(
        {fileId: fileId, alt: 'media',}, 
        {responseType: 'stream'}, (err,  res ) => {
            if (err) {
                returnData.push(["ERR"]);
                returnData.push("" + err);
            } else {
                res.data.pipe(file);
                returnData.push("Downloaded");
            }
            callback(returnData);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = gotData;
```

Comment: It's the google oAuth, I think I followed this documentation for that: https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 9):

From your script, I thought that you may be using the googleapis of the version more than v24.0.0. So how about modifying the version of googleapis? Also I have experienced the same issue with your situation. In my case, the issue was removed by modifying the version of googleapis to v24.0.0.

When I used v25.0.0 - v30.0.0 of googleapis, the error occurs. When it used the googleapis of v24.0.0, the error was removed.

#### Note :

- For the googleapis after the version of v25.0.0, some bugs for APIs and the options are reported. I believe that these bugs are removed in the future. So if for APIs and the options you use, some errors occur, please modify the version of googleapis, and try again. The cases which were solved by modifying the version are as follows.

#### References :

- [How do I update my google sheet in v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898241/how-do-i-update-my-google-sheet-in-v4/48899290#48899290)
- [Create a gmail filter with Gmail API nodejs, Error: Filter doesn't have any criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186534/create-a-gmail-filter-with-gmail-api-nodejs-error-filter-doesnt-have-any-crit/49187226#49187226)
- [Insufficient Permission when trying to create a folder on Google Drive via API(v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204284/insufficient-permission-when-trying-to-create-a-folder-on-google-drive-via-apiv/49204457#49204457)
- [Youtube Data API V3 - Error fetching video with google.youtube.videos.list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310299/youtube-data-api-v3-error-fetching-video-with-google-youtube-videos-list/49310978#49310978)
- [Google drive API - Cannot read property 'OAuth2' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848105/google-drive-api-cannot-read-property-oauth2-of-undefined/49848309)
- [How to run a Google App Script using Google API Service Library (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258645/how-to-run-a-google-app-script-using-google-api-service-library-node-js/50262736#50262736)

If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

How about this modification? In my environment, I confirmed that this modification worked by googleapis of v30.0.0.

#### From :

```
drive.files.get({fileId: fileId, alt: 'media'})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Done');
})
.on('error', err => {
    console.log('Error', err);
})
.pipe(dest);
```

#### To :

```
drive.files.get({fileId: fileId, alt: 'media'}, {responseType: 'stream'},
    function(err, res){
        res.data
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Done');
        })
        .on('error', err => {
            console.log('Error', err);
        })
        .pipe(dest);
    }
);
```

Comment: Well, thank you for your response, but this service I am building is already quite vast and using older version would mean rebuilding too big a portion of it. I will have to try find another way.

Comment: @Richard Franek I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice that you cannot change the version of googleapis from your question. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: I didn't consider the possibility that version may be a solution, you did help a little, I am now creating my own GET method for node.js download since the google's is corrupted. At least, thanks to you, I know the problem wasn't with my code.

Comment: @Richard Franek Please wait for it. I have a modification for your script. I will upload it soon. Can you wait for it? If my modification is not useful for your situation, I would like to think of other methods.

Comment: @Richard Franek I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If this modification didn't work, I'm really sorry.

Comment: Yes, this indeed works. Even before, I got an idea about the solution I posted bellow and that works as well, but I will mark this as the answer because why not.

Comment: @Richard Franek I'm glad your issue was solved. I could also study from your issue. Thank you, too. I would like to add your question to these references of my answer in my future posts. I think that these will be useful for other users.

Comment: where `drive` is imported from?

Comment: @Leonardo Rick I think that the answer of your question of `where drive is imported from?` can be seen at the script of OP's question. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for answering. I was not able to use the properly setup `Auth = require('../authorization/auth_drive/auth');`. Wha't library should I download to do that?

Comment: @Leonardo Rick Thank you for replying. About your issue, can you post it as new question by including your current situation? Because your question is different from this OP's question and also, from your replying, I cannot understand about the detail of your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Google drive Api** and created google docs file. which is stored in google drive. Now i want to export this google docs in MS word Document in **Nodejs**. for which I used google drive export file api which is returning data in *Byte* as mentioned in google drive developer official website [Google Drive Export File](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export). But I want *bytes* data in doc/docx file. So I tried so many things and finally I got solution and now it is working fine.

Now I am able to download google docs in any types of file... In this code I am exporting data in MS wordDocument But If you want download "docs" in another types of file then just change "mimeType" for that just checkout [mimeType Formats](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats). And also change creating file "*Extention*" (resume.*docx*)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const ROOT = require('path').resolve("./")


const Export = async (file_id = '13izcbyZ_eUhY6y6Ac_pYsR0Hip2vaP8WZ4stizsjfR4') => {
    try { 

        // Authenticate with google service account
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({ // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
            keyFile: `${ROOT}/credential.json`,
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',]
        });

        // Acquire an auth client, and bind it to all future calls
        const authClient = await auth.getClient();
        google.options({auth: authClient});
        const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3'});


        let progress = 0;

        // Set the location For store export file
        var dest = await fs.createWriteStream(ROOT + "/public/merge/resume.docx");

        // Calling google drive export api
        let resp = await drive.files.export({
            fileId: file_id,
            mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        }, {responseType: 'stream'});


        resp.data.on('end', function () {
            console.log('Done');
        }).on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Error during download', err);
        }).on('data', d => {
            progress += d.length;
            if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
                process.stdout.clearLine();
                process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
                process.stdout.write(`Downloaded ${progress} bytes`);
            }
        }).pipe(dest)

        let DownloadURL = "localhost:3001/merge/resume.docx";

        return DownloadURL;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err........", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto @Tanaike's answer, here is a promisified version in case someone else arrives here looking for such (like myself):

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  drive.files.get(
    {fileId: image.id, alt: 'media'},
    {responseType: 'stream'},
    (err, res) => {
      res.data.on('end', () => resolve()).on('error', () => reject()).pipe(dest)
    }
  )
})
```