# Self downloading an xlsx file from google Driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

So, i am trying to make a small script that will download a certainly excel file using google drive API, by following google API tutorials i just got stuck with two errors "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" and "the requested conversion is not supported"
here is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}
/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
    var fileId = '1lKhyW1O519_1V1QhL9Vkbu55HqyfrgaUbnF4fmhZqU0';
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/home/oem/Desktop/TTHIS/report-2019-03-26.xls');
    drive.files.export({
    fileId: fileId,
    mimeType: 'xls'
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);


  });

}
```

remembering that the first part of the code is just for authorization, so the real problem starts at the function listFiles().
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

1. In order to use `response.data`, `{responseType: 'stream'}` is used.

   - [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373224/node-js-google-drive-api-download-file-error/50381086#50381086) might be useful for your situation.
   - In the thread, the method of files.get is used. But this can be also used for the method of files.export.
2. There is no mimeType of `xls`. Please use the mimeType of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for xlsx format.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var fileId = '1lKhyW1O519_1V1QhL9Vkbu55HqyfrgaUbnF4fmhZqU0';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/home/oem/Desktop/TTHIS/report-2019-03-26.xls');
drive.files.export({
fileId: fileId,
mimeType: 'xls'
})
.on('end', function () {
  console.log('Done');
})
.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error during download', err);
})
.pipe(dest);
```

To:

```
var fileId = '1lKhyW1O519_1V1QhL9Vkbu55HqyfrgaUbnF4fmhZqU0';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/home/oem/Desktop/TTHIS/report-2019-03-26.xls');
drive.files.export({
  fileId: fileId,
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
}, {responseType: 'stream'}, function(err, response) {
  response.data
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log("Done.");
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
      return process.exit();
    })
    .pipe(dest);
});
```

#### Note:

- If the error related to Drive API occurs, please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at API console, again.
- This modified script supposes that the file of `1lKhyW1O519_1V1QhL9Vkbu55HqyfrgaUbnF4fmhZqU0` is Spreadsheet.

In my environment, I could confirm that this modified script worked. But if this didn't work for your environment, I apologize.

Comment: thank you very much man! it worked like a charm, hope you will have a good day!

Comment: @joao I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: it worked fine for me as well.
my scenario: download a file from google-storage from an API, an download the file to user's machine when requested (button on a webapp)