# Can't download xlsx file through drive api with formatting

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to download a sheet using the drive api that I created programmatically using the sheets api.  When I download that sheet through drive manually it has all formatting in tact, when I use drive api it doesn't.  Not sure what to do to fix it.  Here is my export code ->

```
await drive.files
    .export(
        {
            fileId,
            auth: jwToken,
            mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        },
        { responseType: "stream" }
    )
    .then((resp) => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/google-api-files/temp/temp-sheet.xlsx`);
        resp.data.pipe(dest);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, " :: err in export");
    });
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this I'd love some input.  I haven't found any info online about it.

Edit 1)
As per a suggestion I tried modifying the code to ->

```
await drive.files
    .export(
        {
            fileId: fileId,
            auth: jwToken,
            mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        },
        { responseType: "stream" }
    )
    .then((resp) => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/google-api-files/temp/temp-sheet.xlsx`);
        resp.data.on("finish", () => {
            resp.data.pipe(dest);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, " :: err in export");
    });
```

But the downloaded spreadsheet still is missing formatting

Edit 2)
Here is a photo showing what it looks like ->
[Spreadsheet Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3gyC.png)

Comment: what do you call formatting ?

Comment: i guess you already found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352167/self-downloading-an-xlsx-file-from-google-driver because your code seems close, but they use .xls as extension, not xlsx.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the formatting? What is changing? Consider providing a sample spreadsheet in order to reproduce this.

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO no luck on changing to .xls it still has no formatting, I call formatting things like styling the text, adding background color, borders so just styling the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

To future issue havers, the problem was that even though every is async await, the styles were not fully registered with google before the download started.  Putting the download code inside of the batchUpdate callback fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using on finish to close the write stream. Something like this:

```
dest.on('finish',() => { 

    dest.close(); 

    console.log('Download Completed');  

})
```

Comment: No luck on that approach.