# NodeJS: Get filename from readStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client, node-streams

TLDR; Can I get filename from readable stream?

Got a method to download file from Google Drive and save it to local directory as I'm requesting response as stream , I would like to save the file with the same name as it has on the drive without explicitly asking user.
Do I have to make 1 extra request prior, to get filename from drive , is that the only way ?

```js
async fetchFile(fileID) {
// Get file as stream
    const { data: gdriveFile } = await this.drive.files.get(
      {
        fileId: fileID,
        alt: "media"
      },
      {
        responseType: "stream"
      }
    )
    // FIXME: get filename from gdrive
    console.log("Saving File: " + JSON.stringify(gdriveFile))
    // fs writeStream
    // const destStream = fs.createWriteStream(
    //   path.resolve(destDir + "/" + filename || "bleh.log")
    // )
    // pipeline(gdriveFile, destStream).end(() => {
    //   return "File copied"
    // })
}
```

Thnx

Comment: Doers [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373224/node-js-google-drive-api-download-file-error) answer your question ?

Comment: Nope , In all of the code from the question linked above , the function is explicitly asking for filename for writestream .

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you want to achieve, would you mind providing more details?

Comment: fetchFile is a function with single parameter , fileID
steps 1. function make request to google drive api using drive.files.get() 
step 2. it gets back a response steam , a readable stream 
step 3. then function somehow finds what is the name of the file from the stream
step 4. it creates a write stream of filename from previous step and pipes the readable stream (step 2) to writeable fs stream

Comment: I checked all the docs and related articles and it seems , its a api limitation . google drive api does not provide file metadata when a stream is requested